# Is it possible to connect to database from library jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, utility

I have a problem statement. I am trying to create a library jar which will help anyone to generate report from data. I am creating a springboot java jar for same.

Inputs : SQL statement and Type of report (CSV,PDF etc)

Now the problem is I want this utility to be used by multiple projects/Applications. But the problem is I am not aware how I can connect to database of the project or application which is using this library. I can not provide all the datasources b'cos that is not possible for me. There can be 100s of application which can be using this utility jar so no way i can create that many database connection in my jar and also what if some of the datasource changes in future.Is there any generic way which I can use to achieve same or is this possible somehow to build jar in a way which will pick and connect the datasource of the application or project which is using it.

P.S. are there any tools which i can use to help me out with the same problem statement i.e. pass the sql and it will connect to database for me and get me the results.

Comment: To address the same issue the `Connection` is an interface. You just have to take connection as input, and perform your tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve this by putting all your configurations in a file in every project. Your jar file will use that file and connect to the relative database according to that project configurations.

Your Configuration file i.e; named db_connect.properties should be same in every project you are using. Inside this file there should be keys and values, which will be used by the jar to connect to that particular database.

Here i am showing my database.properties file for a project which is used by a jar. My custom jar is using some extra features, you can ignore them.

```
# Database configuration
jdbcDriver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver  
jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?autoReconnect=true&autoReconnectForPools=true  
username=root123  
password=root123  

partitionCount=2  
maxConnectionsPerPartition=4  
acquireIncrement=1  
acquireRetryDelayInMs=10000  
connectionTestStatement=SELECT 1  
connectionTimeoutInMs=90000  
idleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes=30
```